# Adding a SMTP email to proxyAddresses of the DirectoryEntery

Tags: c#, properties, directoryservices

```
DirectoryEntry toFix = new DirectoryEntry(groupPath, privilegedUserName, privilegedPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

Is there a way to add "SMTP:bleh@myemail.com" to the existing list of toFix.Properties["proxyAddresses"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this MSDN topic: [Setting Properties with Multiple Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Here are some code samples from the link above.

The following code example shows how to use the AddRange method.

```
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Fabrikam/CN=My Username,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com");
ent.Properties["otherTelephone"].AddRange(new object[] {"(425) 523 1462","(523) 125 6321"});
ent.CommitChanges();
```

The following code example shows how to use the Insert method.

```
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Fabrikam/CN=My Username,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com");
ent.Properties["otherTelephone"].Insert(2, "525 623 5423");
ent.CommitChanges();
```

The following code example shows how to use an array to set a value on a multi-value property.

```
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Fabrikam/CN=My Username,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com");
ent.Properties["otherTelephone"][0] = "425 263 6234";
ent.CommitChanges();
```